# Linkify properly an email address with subject

Tags: android, linkify

I want to linkify a email address and put a static subject to the email.

In the layout I have this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:text="@string/email" />
```

How can I add the subject to the email? I should do this in the `Activity` with the `addLinks()` method, am I right? I tried some combinations but the email was being appended to the subject...

I checked those sources but without luck:

- [Email from a link and Android Intents - bring it home](http://gettingintomobile.blogspot.pt/2011/07/email-from-link-and-android-intents.html)
- [Android Text Links Using Linkify](http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/)
- [Linkify your Text!](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView5"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:clickable="true"/>

TextView mailTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
mailTV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:"+getString(R.string.email)+"?subject="+getString(R.string.email_subject)+"\" >"+getString(R.string.email)+"</a>"));
mailTV.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```