# Subject is always empty when I do click on an email in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, textview, mailto, autolink

I'm developing an App and I added a simple **TextView** with *autoLink="email"*

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:text="@string/lblContactUs" />
```

My string looks like this:

```
<string name="lblContactUs">Federico Navarrete <a href="mailto:fanm_45@outlook.com?Subject=Contact%20Us%TipSal" target="_top">fanm_45@outlook.com</a></string>
```

Always, when I do click in the link the subject is empty.

[image: Empty subject]

Also, I noticed that if I don't have a real email inside of the tag:

```
<a href="mailto:fanm_45@outlook.com?Subject=Contact%20Us%TipSal">fanm_45@outlook.com</a>
```

However, I have something like this:

```
<a href="mailto:fanm_45@outlook.com?Subject=Contact%20Us%TipSal">Contact us</a>
```

The link doesn't do anything, the code is fully ignored. Does anyone have any idea what should I change? Or why is not working?

**PS:**
I already tested on Gmail and Blue Mail clients, I got the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linkify properly an email address with subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316000/linkify-properly-an-email-address-with-subject)

Comment: Hi, I don't see the difference, if you see the code: "<a href=\"mailto:"+getString(R.string.email)+"?subject="+getString(R.string.email_subject)+"\" >"+getString(R.string.email)+"</a>". It's the same that I have here: <a href="mailto:fanm_45@outlook.com?Subject=Contact%20Us%TipSal">fanm_45@outlook.com</a> and I already tried it, also with the option of clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think textview can not identify  this `<a href="mailto:"/>`. But textView can identify mail address.

You can change your string.xml to

`<string name="lblContactUs">fanm_45@outlook.com</string>`

The behavior should be the same with

`<string name="lblContactUs"><a href="mailto:">fanm_45@outlook.com</a></string>`

To achieve your requirement you should use the customer span for mail sending.

**1. Set your text can be clicked by usiing `ClickableSpan`**

```
class MyURLSpan : ClickableSpan
{
    MainActivity mActivity;

    public MyURLSpan(MainActivity activity)
    {
        mActivity = activity;
    }
    public override void OnClick(View widget)
    {
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        email.SetType("text/plain"); 
        //real device please use  email.SetType("message/rfc822");
        email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, "mikexxma@outlook.com");  
        email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "hello");    
        email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "hello mike ma");
        mActivity.StartActivity(email);
    }
}
```

**2. Add the click listener to the text:**

```
private SpannableString getClickableSpan()
{
    string s = "contact me";
    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(s);
    sp.SetSpan(new MyURLSpan(this), 0, s.Length, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
    return sp;
}
```

**3. Set the span to the `textview` :**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
     SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    mailTV = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView2);
    mailTV.SetText(getClickableSpan(), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);         
    mailTV.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
}
```

You can find :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer is super amazing :D.